# What is the difference between MySQL and MariaDB in Laravel Sail

Tags: docker, mariadb, laravel-sail

I use MySQL in a project and have to switch to MariaDB. So far I know, it is the same, the only thing I have to do is, to change the image from: `image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'` to `image: 'mariadb:latest'` because it should the same.

docker-compose.yml

```
    mysql:
        image: 'mariadb:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-project-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
```

database.php

```
    'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'mysql'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=<database_name>
DB_USERNAME=<username>
DB_PASSWORD=<password>
```

```
sail artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL:
select 
   table_name as `name`,
   (data_length + index_length) as `size`,
   table_comment as `comment`,
   engine as `engine`,
   table_collation as `collation` 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = '<database_name>' 
  and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)
```

I run `sail artisan up --build` and i run successful.
There DB server is online in Docker an there is no error in the log

```
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 929532a9426d085111c24c63de9c23cc54382259 as process 1
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using ARMv8 crc32 + pmull instructions
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=47959
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 47959; transaction id 16
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240121 17:34:25
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2024-01-21 18:34:25 2024-01-21 17:34:25 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
2024-01-21 18:34:25 Version: '11.2.2-MariaDB-1:11.2.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

In the doc of Laravel I don't find some information about this.
Which config is missing, or wrong in my case?

Comment: Try using `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`, not localhost. You need to use the IP address to make it use TCP, not the UNIX domain socket.

Comment: if i change it, now i get close to the DB: ` SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) ` but, ´artisan migrate´ failed with this error.

Comment: Well, that's progress. At least your client is reaching the container and getting an active response from MariaDB. But it might be bound to another IP interface. Read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/#connecting-to-mariadb-from-outside-the-container

Comment: @BillKarwin After i've changedd the IP address  in `.env` to `DB_HOST=172.18.0.6`  ( I funden in the regarding --> `Docker container --> mariadb:latest instance --> NetworkSetting ->Network-> "project name" -> IPAddress` )  it was possible to start the `artisan migration` successfull. There are also aliases listed in this config, wich are very comfortable, in comparison unsing the ip address.

Comment: @BillKarwin i changed also the keys in the `docker-compose.yml` form `mysql` to `mariadb`, now i can use `DB_HOST=mariadb` in the `.env`-file

Comment: It might be that `mysql` as a command isn't in mariadb:latest and that sail/artisan is trying to use it to create some structures/migration. If there's a configuration option to use `mariadb` instead look at that. Also use [mariadb's healthcheck.sh](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-healthcheck-sh/) to ensure that it is up. `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD` is a bit redundant as you've set passwords for root and non-root users.

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql,` <<== it might be the *volume*, so make another volume, spin up mariadb and then restore the backup of your mysql databases